Specifying Dynamic filenames for AIA and CDP in CAPolicy?
In the "CAPolicy.inf" file where you define [AuthorityInformationAccess] and [CRLDistributionPoint], can these sections use dynamic values? For instance:
[CRLDistirubtionPoint]
URL="http://pki.mycompany.tld/%3%8%9.crl"

or
[CRLDistirubtionPoint]
URL="http://pki.mycompany.tld/<CAName><CRLNameSuffix><DeltaCRLAllowed>.crl"

I did some searching around for the answer, but even Microsoft doesn't have great information regarding this or the proper configuration of AIA and CDP extensions in a two-tier PKI.
Thanks!


In the "CAPolicy.inf" file where you define [AuthorityInformationAccess] and [CRLDistributionPoint], can these sections use dynamic values?

these sections in CAPolicy.inf file are deprecated since Windows Server 2008. You no longer specify these settings in CAPolicy.inf file and configure them in post-installation configuration script where you can use mentioned variables.
